# Debian packaging helper tools for beginners

Tags: debian, software-packaging

I wanted to create my own Debian package for the first time, but I'm scared of the tools that are used in [this tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian). There are several text files that you need to be careful not to break their content structure, there are some directory structure that you have to follow, etc. This seems a perfect thing that could be automated, at least for the beginners.

Is there any tool around that eases Debian package creation process? Doesn't matter whether this would be a cli-prompt or a gui tool - jut not to make me remember dozens of file-level details.

Answer (score 0):

There is much automation already offered. To get started, run `dh_make` (package name is `dh-make`) from inside the directory of your software. This tool will guide you on what needs to be done. It will create a whole bunch of files in `debian/` directory, some of which you'll want to delete and some of which you'll want to edit.

Look at [this guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide) for more information. It may save you hours.

Answer (score 0):

There's always https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm, which aims to address the usability of debian packaging.